# GetElements from a URL with powershell

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, powershell

I am trying to get all links for each object, in order to make a log of which items are new and which are old

I dont understand how to grab links from a shopping website...

Tis is the code that works.

```
$URI = 'http://superwidgets.wordpress.com/category/sql/'
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('h2') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'entry-title' } )
```

(Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26009.getting-information-from-web-pages-via-powershell.aspx )

This code does not

```
$url = 'https://www.norrona.com/nb-NO/o/herre/?displaysize=L%7CM&s=7&h=69000'
$x = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL
($x.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'productcard' } )
```

WHY?

Answer (score 2):

This works but there is no `div` element with a `productcard` classname. `Html` and `Javascript` are just a bunch of text that are not rendered by any browser when retrieved from `PowerShell`. This means all the `javascript` is not executed.

There is a `<script>` element that is:

```
<script src="/api/translation/JavascriptInject?groups=Global&amp;groups=ProductList&amp;groups=Product&amp;groups=Payment&amp;groups=PrePurchase"></script>
<main id="vueProductList" role="main">
</main>
```

that probably should be invoked to render the elements you look for.
But this is another call to another web ressource that probably return `javascript` `objects`. This doesn't tell if the `objects` would be styled with a `productcard` `CSS` class when rendered by `javascript` code.

This is probably not the right way to get the product list. You should directly access the API (if available) to get the list of products. You can then use PowerShell to convert `json` to `powershell` objects with `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet.